# Requesting a review of a rejection of a new Topic with examples

Tags: discussion, documentation

In this example, the rejection included the comment that the user is of the opinion that the individual examples are well written but belong in a different existing Topic.  Meanwhile, I am of a very strong opinion that a new Topic is actually warranted.

I could see no mechanism to publicly comment on the decision to reject the new topic.

What is the correct mechanism to get a rejection of a new Topic with examples by another user appealed or reviewed?